# MappedByteBuffer query

Tags: java

I want to read a 150 MB text file and split the contents of the file into words. When i do this using MappedByteBuffer its taking 12s for a file size of 135 mb . When i do the same with BufferedReader it's taking more time. Is it possible to reduce the time ?

Here is my code.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.MappedByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;


public class mappedcompare {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        long one =System.currentTimeMillis();
        String line=null;



        File f= new File("D:\\dinesh\\janani.txt");
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(f);
        FileChannel fc = fin.getChannel();
        MappedByteBuffer mbb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0L, fc.size());
        String[] words=null;
        ConcurrentHashMap <String,Integer> dictionary=new ConcurrentHashMap<String,Integer>(50,1);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) fc.size()];
        mbb.get(buffer);
        ByteArrayInputStream isr = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer);
        InputStreamReader ip = new InputStreamReader(isr);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ip);
        while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
            line=line.replace(':', ' ');
            line=line.replace(';', ' ');
            line=line.replace('"', ' ');
            line=line.replace('!', ' ');
            line=line.replace(',',' ');
            line=line.replace('.', ' ');
            line =line.replace('/', ' ');
            line=line.replace('\\', ' ');
            line=line.replace('%', ' ');
            line=line.replace('(', ' ');
            line=line.replace(')', ' ');
            line=line.replace('\'', ' ');
        for(String word: line.split("\\s+"))
                {
            dictionary.putIfAbsent(word, 1);

            if(dictionary.containsKey("word")){
                    int value =dictionary.get(word);
                    dictionary.replace(word, ++value);  
                }

                }
        }
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - one);
    fin.close();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, don’t use `ConcurrentHashMap` in a single-threaded operation. There is no benefit of using this class over a simple `HashMap`. In Java 7, `HashMap` does not provide the operations `putIfAbsent`, etc. but that is not a restriction, but a chance to cleanup your `Map` update code:

```
dictionary.putIfAbsent(word, 1);

if(dictionary.containsKey("word")){
        int value =dictionary.get(word);
        dictionary.replace(word, ++value);  
    }
```

Here, you are performing four hash lookup operations, `putIfAbsent`, `containsKey`, `get`, and `replace` where you actually need only two (besides the point the looking for `"word"` rather than `word` looks broken to me):

```
Integer old=dictionary.get(word);
dictionary.put(word, old==null? 1: old+1);
```

This needs only two lookups and works with an ordinary `HashMap`.

---

Next, get rid of the sequence of `line=line.replace(…, ' ');` calls as each of them creates a new `String` where all you really want is to treat these special characters like `' '` within your `split` operation. So you can just adapt your `split` operation to treat these characters as delimiters: `for(String word: line.split("[:;\"!,./\\\\%()'\\s]+"))`.

---

So putting it all together your code becomes more readable which is the bigger win than the few seconds you can save.

```
File f= new File("D:\\dinesh\\janani.txt");
try(FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(f);
    FileChannel fc = fin.getChannel();) {
  final MappedByteBuffer mbb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0L, fc.size());
  HashMap<String, Integer> dictionary=new HashMap<>();
  byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) fc.size()];
  mbb.get(buffer);
  ByteArrayInputStream isr = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer);
  InputStreamReader ip = new InputStreamReader(isr);
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ip);
  while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
    for(String word: line.split("[:;\"!,./\\\\%()'\\s]+")) {
      Integer old=dictionary.get(word);
      dictionary.put(word, old==null? 1: old+1);
    }
  }
}
```

---

Finally I recommend to give `Files.readAllLines(…)` a try. It will depend on the environment whether it is faster but even if it is slightly slower I would prefer it over your `MappedByteBuffer` approach due to the readability win:

```
File f= new File("D:\\dinesh\\janani.txt");
HashMap<String, Integer> dictionary=new HashMap<>();
for(String line:Files.readAllLines(f.toPath(), Charset.defaultCharset())) {
  for(String word: line.split("[:;\"!,./\\\\%()'\\s]+")) {
    Integer old=dictionary.get(word);
    dictionary.put(word, old==null? 1: old+1);
  }
}
```

---

If performance is really that important you may go one level deeper and process you splitting manually on the `byte` level and create `String` only once you found a match. This assumes that you use an encoding which use one `byte` per `char` and maps the lower value (i.e. ASCII characters) directly which is the case for common encoding like the Window CP1258.

```
HashMap<String, Integer> dictionary=new HashMap<>();
final CharsetDecoder cs = Charset.defaultCharset().newDecoder();
assert cs.averageCharsPerByte()==1;
try(FileChannel ch=FileChannel.open(f.toPath(), StandardOpenOption.READ)) {
  MappedByteBuffer mbb=ch.map(MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, ch.size());
  ByteBuffer slice=mbb.asReadOnlyBuffer();
  int start=0;
  while(mbb.hasRemaining()) {
    switch(mbb.get()) {
      case ' ': case   9: case   10: case  11: case  13: case '\f':
      case ':': case ';': case '\\': case '"': case '!': case ',':
      case '.': case '/': case  '%': case '(': case ')': case '\'':
        int pos=mbb.position();
        if(pos>start) {
          slice.limit(mbb.position()).position(start);
          String word=cs.decode(slice).toString();
          Integer old=dictionary.get(word);
          dictionary.put(word, old==null? 1: old+1);
          start=mbb.position();
        }
        start=pos+1;
    }
  }
}
```

This can speedup such a low-level operation significantly at the cost of being not entirely portable.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion . I have tried your method which reduced time by 2 s .Is there any way can make this much faster?. Reading taking less time while that splitting takes more time.

Comment: If Java 8 is being used, I would use [Files.lines(f.toPath(), Charset.defaultCharset())](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-).forEach rather than Files.readAllLines, as readAllLines will load the entire file into memory, while Files.lines will not.  I also would consider making each Map value an int[1], so each increment of a count doesn't create a new Integer object.

Comment: Am using Java 7 ,but i will try your method.

Comment: I wanna reduce the time to less than 2 s . AM thinking of accessing the mappedbytebuffer by multiple threads . Will that work?

Comment: In principle you can access the buffer from multiple threads. The tricky part is the work splitting as you have to find line/word boundaries before you can assign regions of your buffer to the threads.

Comment: Added alternative solution.

Comment: Ya i tried your code, It reduced time by 3 s . Now processing time is 5.5 s .

Comment: Note that changing the JVM and using the `-server` option can make a difference as well…

Answer (score 2):

I tried to reduce the number of operation being made as best as I could. For a sample file that I created this ended up being about 3 times faster than the original code. This will likely not work for most of the more complicated character encodings (see Holger's alternative method answer, that should work with any character encoding).

```
long one = System.currentTimeMillis();

boolean[] isDelimiter = new boolean[127];
isDelimiter[' '] = true;
isDelimiter['\t'] = true;
isDelimiter[':'] = true;
isDelimiter[';'] = true;
isDelimiter['"'] = true;
isDelimiter['!'] = true;
isDelimiter[','] = true;
isDelimiter['.'] = true;
isDelimiter['/'] = true;
isDelimiter['\\'] = true;
isDelimiter['%'] = true;
isDelimiter['('] = true;
isDelimiter[')'] = true;
isDelimiter['\''] = true;
isDelimiter['\r'] = true;
isDelimiter['\n'] = true;

class Counter {

  int count = 0;
}

File f = // your file here
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(f);
FileChannel fc = fin.getChannel();
MappedByteBuffer mbb = fc
    .map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0L, f.length());
Map<String, Counter> dictionary = new HashMap<String, Counter>();

StringBuilder wordBuilder = new StringBuilder();
while (mbb.hasRemaining()) {
  char c = (char) mbb.get();
  if (c < isDelimiter.length && c >= 0 && isDelimiter[c]) {
    if (wordBuilder.length() > 0) {
      String word = wordBuilder.toString();
      wordBuilder.setLength(0);

      Counter intForWord = dictionary.get(word);
      if (intForWord == null) {
        intForWord = new Counter();
        dictionary.put(word, intForWord);
      }
      intForWord.count++;
    }
  } else {
    wordBuilder.append(c);
  }
}

System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - one);
fin.close();
```

Comment: Ya I have tried your code . It worked , this method reduced the time to 3.5 s . Thank you.

Comment: @user3164184 Updated to reuse the same `StringBuilder` instance. Should make it a bit faster.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing all those `replace`s and `split`s with

```
line.split("[:;\"!,./\\\\%()'\\s]+")
```

You can also try using Java's [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to parse the file while streaming. You can pass the above regex to [`useDelimiter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter(java.lang.String)) so it splits on all those characters.